# Probability of sum of 10 dice throws

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If a die is rolled 10 times. What is the probability that the sum of the results is less than or equal to 20?

I was trying to solve this using something like $P(X_1 + X_2 + ....+X_{10} \le 20)$ but was not able to proceed. And, if I try to work out individual cases, it will take a lot of time.

Comment: Use the multinomial distribution

Comment: @Peter I am not sure how to use multinomial distribution as I have just used multinomials for partitions and not for sum of random variables.

Comment: If we want an approximation, and are not too fussy, we can use the normal. This should not be too bad, particularly if we use a continuity correction, and find the probability that the appropriate normal is $\le 20.5$.

Comment: For each partition, the multinomial distribution gives the probability that this particular partition occurs.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I do not think that the normal approximation is very well here. But let's see ...

Comment: @Peter: Nowadays one jusr writes a quick program. But in the old days, for a ballpark estimate, one would stretch the normal approximation beyond the zone of comfort.

Comment: Is it an homework ? May be you are asked to give an approximate answer only : in this case, use a normal approximation N(m=35,\sigma^2=17.5) which gives you something at more than $3 \sigma$ at the left from the mean, otherwise said, less than $0.5$ percent chance of occurrence (less than 1 out of 200 cases are favorable)

Comment: I get the exact result : $0.00289$. What does the normal approximation give ?

Comment: @Peter I used the normal distribution as Andre and Jean suggested and the answer I came up with is $0.0030$. So, I guess it is pretty close.

Comment: Did not expect this. Really close.

Comment: @Peter I am guessing the difference got lost when I converted the fraction to decimal and using the normal table upto only two decimal points.